# Cannot send to database

Tags: php, html, post, mysqli, get

I have been trying to make an admin panel. For the settings, I wanted to run all the scripts in one file so it wouldn't make a mess in the folder. However, when I try to add/edit a row it wouldn't let me.

Note: I can fetch all rows form the database without an issue. Also it does not give an error so I can't look at it.

Here is my code:

```
<? session_start();
include '../database.php';
if (!isset($_SESSION['logged'])) {
header("Location: login.php");
}
if ($_GET['action'] == 'add') {
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/menu.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/atasoy.css">
        <title>Yönetim Paneli - Berru Perde</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Add Slide</h1>
        <br>
        <br>
        <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" align="center">
        <label for="name">Name</label><br><input type="text" name="name"><br>
        <label for="link">Image Link (<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.open('upload1.php', 'Image Upload', 'width=400, height=200');">Upload Image</a>)</label><br>
        <input name="link"><br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add Image">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?
} else {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $link = $_POST['link'];

    $query = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `carousel` VALUES ('', '$name', '$link')");

    header("Location: carousel.php");
}
} elseif ($_GET['action'] == 'edit') {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `carousel` WHERE `id` = '$id'");
    $fetch = $result->fetch_array();
    if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/menu.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/atasoy.css">
        <title>Admin Panel</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Edit Slide</h1>
        <br>
        <br>
        <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" align="center">
        <label for="name">Name</label><br><input type="text" name="name" value="<?=$fetch['name']; ?>"><br>
        <label for="link">Image Link(<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="window.open('upload1.php', 'Image Upload', 'width=400, height=200');">Upload Image</a>)</label><br>
        <input name="link" value="<?=$fetch['link']; ?>"><br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?
} else {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $link = $_POST['link'];

    $mysqli->query("UPDATE `carousel` SET `name`='$name', `link`='$link' WHERE `id`='$id'");
    header("Location: carousel.php");
} # Delete script not done yet
} else {
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/menu.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/atasoy.css">
        <title>Admin Panel</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Slideshow Editor</h1>
        <br>
        <br>
        <ul class="addthings"><a href="carousel.php?action=add"><li><img src="http://www.widgetop.com/images/AddWidgets.png">Yeni Carousel Slaytı Ekle</li></a></ul>
        <table class="listing" align="center">
            <tr>
                <td class="darkblue">ID</td>
                <td class="darkblue">Name</td>
                <td class="darkblue">Preview</td>
                <td class="darkblue">Edit</td>
                <td class="darkblue">Delete</td>
            </tr>
            <?
            $query = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `carousel` ORDER BY `id`");
            while ($fetch = $query->fetch_array()) {
            $i = $fetch['id'];
            if ($i % 2 != 0) {
            echo "<tr class='lightblue'><td>" . $fetch['id'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $fetch['name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td><img src='" . $fetch['link'] . "' width='117.5' height='67.5'></td>";
            echo "<td><a href='carousel.php?action=edit&id=" . $fetch['id'] . "'><img src='http://docs.gimp.org/en/images/dialogs/stock-edit-16.png'></a></td>";
            echo "<td><a href='carousel.php?action=delete&id=" . $fetch['id'] . "'><img src='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/aspneticons_v1.0_Nov2006/delete_16x16.gif'></a></td></tr>";
            } else {
            echo "<tr class='white'><td>" . $fetch['id'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $fetch['name'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td><img src='" . $fetch['link'] . "' width='117.5' height='67.5'></td>";
            echo "<td><a href='carousel.php?action=edit&id=" . $fetch['id'] . "'><img src='http://docs.gimp.org/en/images/dialogs/stock-edit-16.png'></a></td>";
            echo "<td><a href='carousel.php?action=delete&id=" . $fetch['id'] . "'><img src='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/aspneticons_v1.0_Nov2006/delete_16x16.gif'></a></td></tr>";
            }
            }
            ?>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
<? } ?>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So you're saying `$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM carousel WHERE id = '$id'");` returns a result? If so that if/else clause is the place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problems certainly come from the fact that you didn't want to separate your files. You now have a mess aggregated into one file, playing all in itself the rôle of the model, view and controller.

If you can't see any change in the database but the `INSERT` instruction has been executed, then you should see an error. What is in `$mysqli->error`? Activate PHP errors by putting this at the beggining of your script:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

I see that your INSERT section is only executed if `action == add`. Write `$_REQUEST['action']` instead of `$_GET` and put a `<input type="hidden" name="action" value="add">` into your `<form>`, because you are using a POST form and i'm not sure what your URL looks like. Drop the  `action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>"`, it adds useless complexity to your script (action always points to current URL if not defined).

I hope I gave you enough material to help you debug your code ; it would be quite difficult to do tell more without access to the database. The origin of your bug could be a lot of things.

Comment: My URL is www.example.com/admin/carousel.php?action=add or carousel.php?action=edit&id=1 and vice versa. I can reach the database (the slideshows are listed correctly), I just cannot write data. I know that the query gets executed because it executes `header("Location: carousel.php");` and redirects to me to the main page. I will now try the error reporting and put the results in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It was my bad. Apparently `<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; >`was messing up the code. It is now working perfectly fine! Thanks again!